# How to play chosen Vimeo videos in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo-api, embedded-video, vimeo-ios

I'm developing an iOS app which plays Vimeo videos. Its an In App Purchase application. I already have websites where users can buy videos.

Now I'm confused how to deal with Vimeo videos which I uploaded from my Vimeo Pro account in my iOS application. Do I need to use Vimeo API or can I just embed videos in my app? If you recommend using VimeoVideoPlayer and Vimeo API, I don't know the steps. If you recommend embedding, I can create a page in my website which plays videos and I can embed that page in my app. I have heard stories of rejecting apps by Apple which use embed videos. I couldn't understand what Vimeo explains to integrate their videos in mobile app. Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. 

If you have a specific question about an API (for example, you said you didn't understand Vimeo) you ask it specifically.

Comment: hey, thanks for replying. I asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238569/how-to-make-api-request-to-get-private-vimeo-videos-in-objective-c). Its a detailed question of what I have done so far and where I am stuck. I hope you read it and hit me back with a solution. Thanks again